# How to customize all WSO2 Identity Server login related pages

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have followed this guide for customizing login pages: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Login+Pages

This is all fine.

I have checked out the code from version 4.3.3 and made local changes to:
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/release-4.3.3/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint

When dealing with OpenIDConnect/OAuth2 , there are more pages than just the login.jsp involved e.g the page oauth2_authz.jsp. This is also not a problem when replacing the default authenticationendpoint.war with my modified authenticationendpoint.war.

Problems arise however when trying to separately host the custom authenticationendpoint.war under a different URL.

WSO2 Identity Server is configured with an absolute URL to the AuthenticationEndpoint:

```
<AuthenticationEndpointURL>http://localhost:9990/login.do</AuthenticationEndpointURL>
```

And the form of my login.jsp is altered to submit back to the absolute URL for WSO2 Identity Server, instead of the relative URL ../commonauth.

```
<form action="https://localhost:9443/commonauth"...
```

The problems I see is that I am correctly redirected to my custom login page, but the authz page (list of Claims and buttons for Approve | Approve Always | Deny) is still the default page hosted inside WSO2.

I want WSO2 Identity Server to use of all my customized pages, not just login.jsp.

These would typically be

- oauth2_authz.jsp
- oauth2_consent.jsp
- oauth2_error.jsp

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this or point to some documentation about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was addressed in WSO2IS 5.1.0 with [IDENTITY-2977](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2977). With relevant changes, you can customize `samlsso_login`, `oauth2_authz`, `oauth2_error` and `oauth2_consent` URLs using configuration available in `web.xml` file of `authenticationendpoint.war`. Please refer to [relevant section of the web.xml](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/pull/123/files#diff-5b42bebf9bc78efd5b3a2246e36a0a50R5) for further details.